# Please help to count number of devices with Python or Pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have a table with column where more than 50k Devices with chaotic names such as for example (LenovoKeyboardl4, MouseM4Apple, LeftHMicrosoftHeadphones, HPMouse4, etc)

And i want to count how many there of Mouses, Keyboards, Headphones, monitors etc.

Because to do this manually will take me forever, is there any other easier method to do that?

Comment: Could you provide an example of your dataframe?

Comment: im sorry, may i ask what is dataframe? Im new to python, I have an excel file with data

Comment: @Alex You can edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output (in text form - so we can copy and paste it, use `Ctrl`+`K` for formatting text for example). It can be few lines from the CSV file correctly formatted and what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression to see if the name contains a particular string and aggregate by that:

```
select type, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (case when name like '%mouse%' then 'mouse'
                   when name like '%keyboard%' then 'keyboard'
                   when name like '%headphone%' then 'headphone'
                   when name like '%monitor%' then 'monitor'
                   else 'something else'
              end) as type
      from t
     ) t
group by type;
```

This picks up the *first* matching string in the name based on the ordering in the `case` expression.  It might miss a lot -- so you'll have to refine the logic based on your data.

What you should really do is change your data processing so you have a "type" column of some sort.  But this might help you get started.